# apache 2.4 modules one handler calling a function in another handler with same name

Tags: apache2, shared-libraries

I am using apache server 2.4 for the deployment of a web application for which I have created two custom C modules with request handlers **Handler1** & **Handler2**. These are properly added and configured in httpd.conf file for handling specific requests related to my application.

The issue is that I have a function **void foo(char*, char*)** with the same name and signature in both the custom module .so files which are loaded into the apache server without any problem. But there is a case when the Handler2 is handling a request and i make the call **foo()** the function from the Handler1 is invoked. And after **Handler1::foo()** is done the control again comes back to Handler2.

Any idea as to what could be a reason behind this kind of behavior ?

Comment: Most modules can be entirely static except for the register_hooks function. You can also just namespace protect the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the foo() function does not need to be exported, and you can declare it static, or you need to properly manage symbol visibility. See for example (this is for AIX, but the concepts are exactly the same):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-symbol-visibility/